# C#: How many bytes to read from a NetworkStream of a chat using a Unicode encoding?

Tags: c#, unicode, chat

I've followed a tutorial of a chat using the ASCII encoding to send/receive messages, and it used to read 4096 bytes in a row to write on the chat client. But now I've changed the encoding to unicode and I know that Unicode use more bytes per character.

My code is the following:

```
taskOpenEndpoint = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                serverStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                byte[] message = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                try
                {
                    bytesRead = serverStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if(flag_chiusura == false)
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    return;
                }
                UnicodeEncoding encoder = new UnicodeEncoding();
                AddMessage(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        });
```

Should I change the number of bytes read, now that I'm using the Unicode encoding?

Comment: Unfortunately this implementation is naive and faulty (you might not see anything bad happen, but it's a classic case of "most of the time it will seem to work fine"). The problem is that `Read` won't necessarily give you back what `Write` sent, so messages sent in one go might be delivered in any number of pieces. If this does happen, the Unicode version will break harder than the ASCII one. There is no correct answer to your question because the question is based on the false premise that there is some "correct" amount of bytes to read.

Answer (score 5):

Switching to Unicode certainly will have an impact on this code.  It is buggy code, it assumes that you'll read a "packet" of data from the socket.  This is only the case if you use a UDP socket, TCP sockets implement a *stream*.  Where the number of bytes you read from a socket is entirely unpredictable and will not match the number of bytes transmitted at the other end of the network connection.

Your Thread.Sleep() call is a workaround of sorts.  It is however an extremely evil kind of fix.  For one, it is placed at the wrong spot, sleeping after you read instead of before you read.  Much worse, it provides no guarantee that the bug is actually fixed, it the app on the other end of the wire also suffers a delay, when the machine is heavily loaded for example, then you still won't read a "packet".  This doesn't happen nearly often enough to ever have a shot at debugging the problem.  And that this is a problem on a machine that's a thousand miles away of course makes it entirely impossible.

So using Unicode increases the odds that your app will crash.  The Encoder will throw when it is asked to decode a partial byte sequence.

You need to fix the bug.  Delete the Thread.Sleep() call.  Turn a TCP stream in a stream of packets by *first* transmitting the number of bytes in the packet.  The receiver can now read the length and knows how often to loop, repeatedly calling Read() until it has received all the bytes.  After this, decoding can of course never cause any trouble.

Comment: Thanks. How to turn a tcp stream into a stream of packets? Which library should I use?

I've updated the code regardind the task.

Comment: Wow, TCP doesn't use packets?  Guess I better turn in my copy of "Illustrated"...  Seriously.  4096 is a bit big, Hopefully an 8-byte message length will never ever get split up eh Hans?  If he could wait for the read buffer to reach n chars (or bytes) he ought to be OK.  Unfortunately `NetworkStream.Length`, glaringly, isn't supported.  I seem to recall available from WINSOCK, knowing window size, but apparently accepted wisdom says reading 1 byte at a time is the only way to avoid blocking.  A sledgehammer: Fill a raw byte[16384] 1 byte at a time re-decoding till 4096 characters are counted.

Comment: @user3603880 4096 may be too big for a "real" packet... (sure you could use IP fragmentation, but why?)

Comment: @ebyrob I haven't understood what you are saying, is it ok or not?

Comment: @user3603880 The 4096 (or larger 16384) and comment about fragmentation is more about UDP.  TCP is generally the simpler implementation to deal with in most scenarios.

Comment: "The Encoder will throw when it is asked to decode a partial byte sequence."  - Does that mean the three-parameter constructor with `bool throwOnInvalidBytes` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following would work without changing your protocol:

Note: It's good to have **some** notion of record/start/end other than just block size.

```
taskOpenEndpoint = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        UnicodeEncoding enc = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false, false);
        while (true)
        {
           serverStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
           byte []message = new byte[16384];
           int bytesRead = 0;
           try {

     // --------- first version may avoid blocking:
               while( encoder.GetCharCount(message, 0, bytesRead) < 4096 
                  && bytesRead < message.Length )
               {
                  if( serverStream.DataAvailable /* && !timed_out */ )
                      message[bytesRead++] = serverStream.ReadByte();
                  else
                      Thread.Sleep(10);  // Better to wait than sleep...
               }

     // --------- second version will fully block:  
               while( encoder.GetCharCount(message, 0, bytesRead) < 4096
                      && bytesRead < message.Length)
                   bytesRead += server.Read(
                        message, 
                        bytesRead, 
                        168384 - message.Length);

           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               if(flag_chiusura == false)
                   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
               return;
           }
           AddMessage(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
           Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    });
```

It could be more efficient by figuring out GetByteCount(decoded) and only re-decoding the portion that hasn't already been fully decoded.